# Vaadin + VisJs: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vaadin, vis.js

The problem is:
`ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded`
appearing at the browser as a notification dialog.

The steps are:

- Using vaadin and creating a component for vis-js. Importing the vis-network any way you want, doesn't affect. Right now, my code has `UI.getCurrent().getPage().addJavaScript("https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.js");` but I've also used `@JsModule` and `@JavaScript` before.
- Adding that component to a `View`.
- Running a Js to create a simple graph (copy-pasted from vis-js examples page). No matter at which point in the lifecycle this is called.

The project setup is:

- vis-network.js 9.1.0
- Chrome browser 96.0.4664.110
- Spring Boot 2.6.2-SNAPSHOT
- Vaadin spring boot starter 14.7.7
- Node v14.17.3
- Java 16.0.1
- Gradle 7.1

I'm gonna answer my own question. I wished to put here to help others and my future self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless hours, the solution here was to set a style for the container informing the size of the container, for example:

```java
div.getStyle().set("width", "600px").set("height", "400px");
```

or via css

```css
      #mynetwork {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }
```

where that div is the one you passed to:

```js
...
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```